# NGINX rewriting some externals URL when enabling SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm having a weird issue with NGINX, when enabling SSL some externals ressources URL get rewritten with the server_name as a base.

For example, trying to include 'https:/fonts.googleapis.com', the browser try to load 'https://my.domain.com/fonts.googleapis.com', but some ressources work ! For example, code.jquery.com work, as you will see in the example provided.

This is happening ONLY with SSL, not using it load the ressources just fine.

I managed to get a working example at those two URL, check your console for the error :

- Non-SSL (Working) : [redacted]
- SSL (Not working) : [redacted]

Both link target the same file, which try to load 2 JS (one from fonts.googleapis.com (failing) and the other one from code.jquery.com (working)).

Here is my NGINX conf :

```
server {
    listen [redacted];
    server_name [redacted];
    include php7.2.conf;

    root /var/www/[redacted]/test;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 150m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}

server {
    listen [redacted]:443 ssl;  
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/public.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers "kEECDH+ECDSA kEECDH kEDH HIGH +SHA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !DSS !PSK !SRP !CAMELLIA !SEED !RC4";
    server_name test.[redacted];
    include php7.2.conf;

    root /var/www/[redacted]/test;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 150m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

I'm kinda lost on this one, so if someone has an idea, thanks !

Comment: If you've put `https:/` instead of `https://` (as you have in your question) then the browser will treat it as a relative URL which points to your server and not the external server.

Comment: And now, I feel kinda stoopid, thanks a lot ! It indeed fix the issue !

I have a sub-question, why is it working on non-ssl then ?

Anyway, thanks a lot, really !